# Windows taskbar unresponsive and always showing the busy Icon. Explorer.exe process crashes frequently

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, crash, taskbar

I strongly suspect a rogue application (or service or bug) in my Windows 8 laptop which kills my explorer process and at times makes the taskbar unresponsive showing the busy icon all the time. Hence I have to use Alt+Tab to switch over between application.  When the taskbar becomes unresponsive I cant even switch between applications, I  have to use the task manager to run the explorer process.

I have 6gb RAM on my laptop

So how to boil down to a possible rouge application(I have tried almost all techniques but in vain) and how to solve this problem if there are no rouge applications.

I consistently see the following 3 errors in the event logs:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: explorer.exe
P2: 6.2.9200.16628
P3: 51a94434
P4: ntdll.dll
P5: 6.2.9200.16579
P6: 51637f77
P7: c0000005
P8: 00000000000054ec
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\ALI\AppData\Local\Temp\WER7C5A.tmp.appcompat.txt
C:\Users\ALI\AppData\Local\Temp\WER7C7A.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
C:\Users\ALI\AppData\Local\Temp\WER7D37.tmp.hdmp
C:\Users\ALI\AppData\Local\Temp\WERC52E.tmp.mdmp

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\ALI\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_explorer.exe_b6c9fc2275b8269316d2d695cbf3f2ff98e379_cab_13c6edd1

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 164f935e-f6ea-11e2-be89-60eb69184d3d
Report Status: 112
Hashed bucket: 

==
Faulting application name: backgroundTaskHost.exe, version: 6.2.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x5010a827
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16451, time stamp: 0x50988aa6
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000003811c
Faulting process id: 0x205c
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce8af7d0fda8cf
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\backgroundTaskHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 188b1b81-f6eb-11e2-be89-60eb69184d3d
Faulting package full name: MarthaStewartLivingOmnime.EverydayFood_1.0.1.2_neutral__p79skxyasf6gr
Faulting package-relative application ID: App

===

Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: WPNConnectionFailure
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: Data Reconnect
P2: 8007274c
P3: WNP
P4: Unknown
P5: Unknown
P6: Unknown
P7: 2
P8: 244
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\ALI\AppData\Local\Temp\wpn_5487237965553919453.evtx

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\ALI\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\NonCritical_Data Reconnect_1249b4f85ef55958ef36b1d42e2e8e111cf3dd8c_cab_1cc161dc

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: e9a99e36-f6ba-11e2-be89-60eb69184d3d
Report Status: 116
Hashed bucket: 

===

The description for Event ID 1903 from source HHCTRL cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=45839
```

I uninstalled the Marthstewart recipe tile (as it showed up in the logs above) yet the problem persists, Moreover I tried all the tweakUI cleaning tools and various other diagnostic tools but nothing seems to even diagnose the problem.

**Update:**

I finally [managed to get the full dump of Explorer.exe it is a large file, hence I have uploaded it here](http://sdrv.ms/13y0IHG)(now deleted).

After uninstalling  a number of programs with revo(probable culprit google drive was also fully cleaned) I got the explorer.exe back , i.e it was atleast running from the previous error 0x10000142, where explorer.exe could not even be started , but that was shortlived I again get this error when I try to restart the explorer.exe process from task manager, the explorer process just fails to restart since the last time it crashed , infact even during the boot time I get this error "Explorer.exe was unable to start correctly (0x0000142)" thus rendering a blank screen with nothing to do , you could only work in safe mode now!.

[I asked the MS support team here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/explorerexe-was-unable-to-start-correctly/bce15d9c-8bd9-41ba-bd25-50855fbc8ec7) , there are similar questions still unanswered by their team.

**Update:**

An answerer found Avast to be the problem for explorer nable to start, but the crash problem continued, now I have narrowed down the problem to the right click context menu only , whenever I press start and type something to search or click a tile , than immediately the explorer process crashes. Also if I **right click any icon anywhere** ,the explorer crashes. So now the problem boils down to how to resolve this right click context menu problem. So how to resolve this? Is there an alternative to the tile view as I need to access the control panel and various apps ?

Also is there any alternative that I can use to access control panel and other settings as I cant use right click nor metro tiles?

Comment: Does the taskbar always show a busy cursor, or only once something breaks? Did it work before?

Comment: Does it happen right after you successfully boot into Windows? If so, have you tried selectively enabling only critical applications in msconfig?

Comment: @gronostaj It always shows a busy cursor , it does not necessarily happen close to the boot time. I strongly suspect a rouge app, but cant just figure out which.

Comment: @happy_soil No it happens quite after sometime

Comment: You can place a bounty on the question if you'd like to draw attention.

Comment: follow the steps from here ad upload the dumps: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ

Comment: @magicandre1981 I had tried this too from the MS support but its not even creating  a directory c:\localdumps

Comment: is the Error reporting service running? check this under **services.msc**

Comment: @magicandre1981 there is no service by that name in my system

Comment: the correct name is "Windows Error reporting service" . Make sure the .reg file is correctly added: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx (open regedit and go to the keys and make sure the data are added). You can also use Procdump to get dumps: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-10-ProcDump-Triggers#time=00m58s

Comment: @magicandre1981 poopup shows successfully added but when i manually check, it is not added, i repeated several times but the script is not adding it

Comment: add the setting yourself. Create a new key with the Name Explorer.exe and a reg_sz Dumpfolder and insert a path to where you want to store the dump files. Also create a DWORD DumpType an set it to 2 to get full dumps. This is explained in the MSDN link I gave you.

Comment: ok, I posted an answer.

Comment: Try installing [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) and going to `Tools` > `Startup` and then select the `Context Menu` tab. See what third party context menu items are listed and disable/delete them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To analyze the issue yourself follow those steps:

- [install Windbg](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2013/06/13/debugging-tools-for-windows-direct-download/)
- [setup debugging symbols](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us)

Open WinDbg, open the dump (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>) and type this command and press ENTER:

```
!analyze -v
```

Now compare the output with what I posted and look if you have the same issue or a new one.

////////////////////

*Edit 2013-08-06*

Last dump shows **C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 9.0\Acrobat Elements\ContextMenu64.dll** as cause:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for ContextMenu64.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for ContextMenu64.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for Adist64.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for Adist64.dll
APPLICATION_VERIFIER_LOCKS_LOCK_IN_UNLOADED_DLL (201)
Unloading DLL containing an active critical section.
This stop is generated if a DLL has a global variable containing a critical section
and the DLL is unloaded but the critical section has not been deleted. To debug
this stop use the following debugger commands:
$ du parameter3 - to dump the name of the culprit DLL.
$ .reload dllname or .reload dllname = parameter4 - to reload the symbols for that DLL.
$ !cs -s parameter1 - dump information about this critical section.
$ ln parameter1 - to show symbols near the address of the critical section.
This should help identify the leaked critical section.
$ dps parameter2 - to dump the stack trace for this critical section initialization. 
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000160384b0, Critical section address. 
Arg2: 0000000001381220, Critical section initialization stack trace. 
Arg3: 000000000ffc49b2, DLL name address. 
Arg4: 0000000016020000, DLL base address. 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for sppc.dll - 
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for SugarSyncShellExt_x64.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for SugarSyncShellExt_x64.dll

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 000007feb74da7fc (verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx+0x00000000000006d0)
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  STATUS_BREAKPOINT

PROCESS_NAME:  explorer.exe

CRITICAL_SECTION:  00000000160384b0 -- (!cs -s 00000000160384b0)

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {AUSNAHME}  Haltepunkt  Im Quellprogramm wurde ein Haltepunkt erreicht.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - Mindestens ein Argument ist ung ltig.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

NTGLOBALFLAG:  2000100

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  48004

APP:  explorer.exe

FAULTING_THREAD:  0000000000000df4

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  STATUS_BREAKPOINT

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STATUS_BREAKPOINT

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 000007feb74e557b to 000007feb74da7fc

STACK_TEXT:  
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch
verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx
verifier!AVrfpFreeMemLockChecks
verifier!AVrfpFreeMemNotify
verifier!AVrfpDllUnloadCallback
ntdll!AVrfDllUnloadNotification
ntdll!LdrpUnloadNode
ntdll!LdrpDecrementNodeLoadCount
ntdll!LdrUnloadDll
KERNELBASE!FreeLibrary
ContextMenu64
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
Adist64
Adist64
0x0
0x0
ContextMenu64
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0


SYMBOL_NAME:  contextmenu64+110a6


IMAGE_NAME:  ContextMenu64.dll

    Image path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 9.0\Acrobat Elements\ContextMenu64.dll
    Image name: ContextMenu64.dll
    Timestamp:        Mon Oct 06 21:22:22 2008 (48EA656E)
    CheckSum:         001880E9
    ImageSize:        00189000
    File version:     9.0.0.373
    Product version:  9.0.0.373
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
```

AppVerifier does a fantastic job to show you all buggy, old and incompatible software you use.

////////////////

the dump shows that Avast (AVAST Software\Avast\snxhk64.dll) causes the Explorer crash:

```
APPLICATION_VERIFIER_MEMORY_SIZE_HEAP_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION (618)
Unexpected exception when trying to find heap block size.
This stop is generated if we get an exception while calling HeapSize for a heap block
that is being freed. This typically means that the specified heap block address is
incorrect or the heap is corrupted.
To debug this stop:
$ .exr parameter3 - to display the exception record;
$ .cxr parameter4 followed by kb - to display the exception context information
and stack trace at the time when the exception was raised. 
Arguments:
Arg1: 000000000474d800, Address of the heap block being freed. 
Arg2: 0000000003680000, Heap handle. 
Arg3: 0000000000caeea0, Exception record. Use .exr to display it. 
Arg4: 0000000000cae9b0, Context record. Use .cxr to display it. 

FAULTING_IP: 
verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx+6d0
000007fb`a324a7fc cc              int     3

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  0000000000caeea0 -- (.exr 0xcaeea0)
ExceptionAddress: 000007fbb16fab00 (ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0x00000000000000c0)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000001
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000024
Attempt to write to address 0000000000000024

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  STATUS_BREAKPOINT

PROCESS_NAME:  explorer.exe

CONTEXT:  0000000000cae9b0 -- (.cxr 0xcae9b0)
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=000007fba32842a0 rcx=00000000fffffffc
rdx=0000000000000088 rsi=0000000000000088 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=000007fbb16fab00 rsp=0000000000caef70 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=ffffffffffffffff  r9=0000000000000004 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000246 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=000007f60b35e000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe cy
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010213
ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0xc0:
000007fb`b16fab00 ff4024          inc     dword ptr [rax+24h] ds:00000000`00000024=????????
Resetting default scope

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {AUSNAHME}  Haltepunkt  Im Quellprogramm wurde ein Haltepunkt erreicht.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - Mindestens ein Argument ist ung ltig.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

NTGLOBALFLAG:  2000100

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  48004

APP:  explorer.exe

FAULTING_THREAD:  0000000000000428

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  STATUS_BREAKPOINT

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STATUS_BREAKPOINT

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 000007fba3252861 to 000007fba324a7fc

STACK_TEXT:  
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject
ntdll!RtlReportExceptionEx
ntdll!RtlReportException
ntdll!LdrpCalloutExceptionFilter
ntdll!LdrpInitializeNode$filt$1
ntdll!_C_specific_handler
ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
ntdll!RtlDispatchException
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch
verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx
verifier!AVrfpSizeHeapExceptionFilter
verifier!AVrfpRtlFreeHeap$filt$0
ntdll!_C_specific_handler
ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
ntdll!RtlDispatchException
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch
ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection
ntdll!RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended
verifier!AVrfpFreeMemLockChecks
verifier!AVrfpFreeMemNotify
verifier!AVrfpRtlFreeHeap
snxhk64!SnxHk_UninstallHook
snxhk64
verifier!AVrfpInitializeExceptionChecking
verifier!DllMain
ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine
ntdll!LdrpInitializeNode
ntdll!LdrpInitializeGraph
ntdll!AVrfInitializeVerifier
ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess
ntdll!_LdrpInitialize
ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
snxhk64!SnxHk_UninstallHook+7150
00000000`5d14fb40 85c0            test    eax,eax

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  c

SYMBOL_NAME:  snxhk64!SnxHk_UninstallHook+7150

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: snxhk64

IMAGE_NAME:  snxhk64.dll

    Loaded symbol image file: snxhk64.dll
    Image path: C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\snxhk64.dll
    Image name: snxhk64.dll
    Timestamp:        Thu May 09 10:52:55 2013 (518B63E7)
    CheckSum:         00000000
    ImageSize:        0004D000
    File version:     8.0.1489.300
    Product version:  8.0.1489.300
    File flags:       0 (Mask 17)
    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
    File type:        0.0 Unknown
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0000.04b0
    CompanyName:      AVAST Software
    ProductName:      avast! Antivirus
    InternalName:     snxhk
    OriginalFilename: snxhk.dll
    ProductVersion:   8.0.1489.300
    FileVersion:      8.0.1489.300
    FileDescription:  avast! snxhk
    LegalCopyright:   Copyright (c) 2013 AVAST Software
```

[Report this issue to Avast](http://forum.avast.com/index.php?board=2.0) and use a different AV tool until they fixed the issue.

Run the uninstall.reg I linked to disable the dump creation and Application Verifier which slows down the Explorer.

// Edit: The new crash is casued by the bluetooth driver:

```
APPLICATION_VERIFIER_LOCKS_LOCK_NOT_INITIALIZED (210)
Critical section not initialized.
This stop is generated if a critical section is used without being
initialized or after it has been deleted. To debug this stop:
$ ln parameter1 - to show symbols near the address of the critical section.
This should help identify the critical section. 
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000009044c08, Critical section address. 
Arg2: 0000000000000000, Critical section debug info address. 
Arg3: 0000000000000000, Not used. 
Arg4: 0000000000000000, Not used. 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for GROOVEEX.DLL - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for SugarSyncShellExt_x64.dll - 

FAULTING_IP: 
verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx+6d0
000007ff`bba9a7fc cc              int     3

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 000007ffbba9a7fc (verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx+0x00000000000006d0)
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  STATUS_BREAKPOINT

PROCESS_NAME:  explorer.exe

CRITICAL_SECTION:  0000000009044c08 -- (!cs -s 0000000009044c08)

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {AUSNAHME}  Haltepunkt  Im Quellprogramm wurde ein Haltepunkt erreicht.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - Mindestens ein Argument ist ung ltig.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

NTGLOBALFLAG:  2000100

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  48004

APP:  explorer.exe

FAULTING_THREAD:  0000000000000978

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  STATUS_BREAKPOINT

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STATUS_BREAKPOINT

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 000007ffbbaa5338 to 000007ffbba9a7fc

STACK_TEXT:  
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject
ntdll!RtlReportExceptionEx
ntdll!RtlReportException
verifier!AVrfpVectoredExceptionHandler
ntdll!RtlpCallVectoredHandlers
ntdll!RtlDispatchException
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch
verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx
verifier!AVrfpVerifyInitializedCriticalSection
verifier!AVrfpRtlDeleteCriticalSection
BtvAppExt!DllUnregisterServer
BtvAppExt!DllUnregisterServer
BtvAppExt
BtvAppExt
combase!CServerContextActivator::CreateInstance
combase!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance
combase!CApartmentActivator::CreateInstance
combase!CProcessActivator::CCICallback
combase!CProcessActivator::AttemptActivation
combase!CProcessActivator::ActivateByContext
combase!CProcessActivator::CreateInstance
combase!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance
combase!CClientContextActivator::CreateInstance
combase!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance
combase!ICoCreateInstanceEx
combase!CoCreateInstance
shell32!_SHCoCreateInstance
shell32!SHExtCoCreateInstance
shell32!HDXA_QueryContextMenu
shell32!CDefFolderMenu::QueryContextMenu
shlwapi!SHInvokeCommandOnContextMenu2
shlwapi!SHInvokeCommandOnContextMenu
shell32!SHInvokeCommandOnSelection
shell32!`Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<5> >::Create'::`2'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'module''
shell32!CRegDataDrivenCommand::_Invoke
explorerframe!CRibbonCommandHandlerOnExplorerCommand::Execute
UIRibbon!CControlUser::_ExecuteOnHandler
UIRibbon!CGenericControlUser::SetValueImpl
UIRibbon!CGenericDataSource::SetValue
UIRibbon!OfficeSpace::DataSource::SetValue
UIRibbon!OfficeSpace::FSControl::SetValue
UIRibbon!NetUI::DeferCycle::ProcessDataBindingPropertyChangeRecords
UIRibbon!NetUI::DeferCycle::HrAddDataBindingPropertyChangeRecord
UIRibbon!NetUI::Binding::SetDataSourceValue
UIRibbon!NetUI::Bindings::OnBindingPropertyChanged
UIRibbon!NetUI::Node::OnPropertyChanged
UIRibbon!FlexUI::Concept::OnPropertyChanged
UIRibbon!NetUI::Node::FExecuteCommand
UIRibbon!FlexUI::ExecuteAction::OnCommand
UIRibbon!NetUI::Node::FExecuteCommand
UIRibbon!NetUI::SimpleButton::OnEvent
UIRibbon!NetUI::Element::_DisplayNodeCallback
UIRibbon!GPCB::xwInvokeDirect
UIRibbon!GPCB::xwInvokeFull
UIRibbon!DUserSendEvent
UIRibbon!NetUI::Element::FireEvent
UIRibbon!NetUI::_FireClickEvent
UIRibbon!NetUI::SimpleButton::OnInput
UIRibbon!NetUI::Element::_DisplayNodeCallback
UIRibbon!GPCB::xwInvokeDirect
UIRibbon!GPCB::xwInvokeFull
UIRibbon!BaseMsgQ::xwProcessNL
UIRibbon!DelayedMsgQ::xwProcessDelayedNL
UIRibbon!ContextLock::~ContextLock
UIRibbon!HWndContainer::xdHandleMessage
UIRibbon!ExtraInfoWndProc
user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow
user32!DispatchMessageWorker
explorerframe!CExplorerFrame::FrameMessagePump
explorerframe!CExplorerTask::InternalResumeRT
explorerframe!CRunnableTask::Run
shell32!CShellTask::TT_Run
shell32!CShellTaskThread::ThreadProc
shell32!CShellTaskThread::s_ThreadProc
SHCore!COplockFileHandle::v_GetHandlerCLSID
verifier!AVrfpStandardThreadFunction
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart


Image path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Bluetooth Suite\BtvAppExt.dll
Image name: BtvAppExt.dll
Timestamp:        Fri Jan 15 13:41:32 2010 (4B50627C)
CheckSum:         000329B6
ImageSize:        0002D000
File version:     1.0.0.1
Product version:  1.0.0.1
File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
File type:        2.0 Dll
File date:        00000000.00000000
Translations:     0409.04e4
CompanyName:      TODO: <Company name>
ProductName:      TODO: <Product name>
InternalName:     BtvAppExt.dll
OriginalFilename: BtvAppExt.dll
ProductVersion:   1.0.0.1
FileVersion:      1.0.0.1
FileDescription:  TODO: <File description>
LegalCopyright:   TODO: (c) <Company name>.  All rights reserved.
```

The [Bluetooth Extension is so buggy that Directory Opus blocked it 2 years ago.](http://blog.dopus.com/2011_11_01_archive.html)

> Blacklisted problematic shell extension: Qualcomm Atheros
>   Commnucations Bluetooth Suite (BtvAppExt.dll,
>   {B8952421-0E55-400B-94A6-FA858FC0A39F}).

Comment: zip the dumps with 7zip into 7z fies (LZMA2 and ULTRA). This reduces the size. New crash is casued by your Bluetooth driver.

Comment: Ya I had uninstalled bluetooth yet the problem persists. But as I told you the link of uninstalling application verifier does not work in my case as i dont have this installed already. @harrymc

Comment: upload all dump and and **NEVER** disable AppVerifier until we fixed all issues because this HIDE the issue again, because Application Verifier stops at the point were the **issue occurs** and not later in normal usage which makes it much harder to debug this issue.

Comment: @magicandre1981 You are a valuable contributor, and so is harrymc , he may have given wrong approach according to you to solve this problem , but that may be my fault as he would not know the full context. We are all humans and hence liable to err let us not fight over this. Both have valid perspectives. Reg bluetooth extentions I had uninstalled them all but still this problem persists. I will upload the file

Comment: @magicandre1981 This approach of analysing crashdump seems to be promising to find the rouge driver \dll etc . I have uploaded the new dump here :http://sdrv.ms/16v3o9K

Comment: this time it is the Intel Driver (hccutils.dll). I've seen this very often in dumps. Update the GPU drivers and if this doesn't fix it, use ShellExView to disable the Intel shell extension.

Comment: I disabled this without restart it worked once and then again the same problem . This is the only intel module shown : GraphicsShellExt Class Yes Context Menu igfxpph Module 8.15.10.2858 Intel(R) Common User Interface Intel Corporation No No No No No No C:\WINDOWS\system32\igfxpph.dll {3AB1675A-CCFF-11D2-8B20-00A0C93CB1F4} 9/14/2012 10:45:42 PM 11/28/2012 7:12:07 AM No Directory\Background A 376,320 No

Comment: some users reported that you have to disable the *igfxcpl.cpl* by saying *don't load* this one: http://tweaks.com/windows/36872/remove-c111ntrol-panel-065pplets/ if this also doesn't fix it, upload the latest dumps.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I tried that does not work , I individually disabled contextmenus using autoruns , restarted yet problem persists, the new dump:http://sdrv.ms/13IzDxS

Comment: it worked, you get a new issue. Your extremely old Adobe Elements from 2008 causes the issue now. Disable this Dll with ShellExView: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 9.0\Acrobat Elements\ContextMenu64.dll**

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks a lot it really worked for the first time without even restarting, do update this process as answer and I will accept this after 24hrs

Comment: I really need that windbg , this seems to be a very useful tool , can you host a direct link for the exe file of windbg for my windows 8 64bit intel i5 machine. I had tried all ways to install windbg , but I was unable to get it

Comment: Thanks for update , the explorer no longer crashes on rightclick and now I can see the menu, but randomly it has crashed twice uptill now hence really need that windbg , this seems to be a very useful tool , can you host a direct link for the exe file of windbg for my windows 8 64bit intel i5 machine. I had tried all ways to install windbg , but I was unable to get it.

Comment: I have exited this post, as you seem to be getting it more-or-less up and running. I don't like it when products that worked together once now suddenly start having conflicts, so I would still counsel caution.

Comment: @harry I agree I myself wondered how this adobe dll which was working fine before suddenly misbehaved? I strongly suspect that the problem is much deeper coz I am still getting explorer crashes , but they are now very rare. Earlier I never had this explorer crashes for about a year

Comment: I've edited my post with steps to debug it yourself. If you have new outputs and you don't know to interpret them, upload the dumps. If you haven't got new crashes for 2-3 days, disable AppVerifier again with my 2nd .reg file.

Comment: @Ali: +1. What you do here is probably enough for quite some time, until the time comes to reinstall Windows (or rather Refresh). I don't think it's possible to find out the true cause via this forum.

Comment: @harrymc I still dont know how to uninstall appVerifier, it seems my system does not have this in the first place as discussed earlier, where I gave a screenshot of my reg key

Comment: run the reg file I posted: http://cid-128fc518635be2dc.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/MS%20Foren/Registry/WER%5E_Explorer_full_uninstall.reg. Removing the Explorer.exe key under **Image File Execution Options** entry kills AppVerifier. And Adobe was buggy from day 0 but may not noticed this issues and repro them in a way that you see that it was the cause of Adobe. That's why Appverifier (like DriverVerifier in kernel mode for drivers) is so awesome to find such hidden bugs.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I am getting an explorer crash twice a day now without any apparent triggers, it seems it happens randomly , here is the new dump : http://sdrv.ms/1cp3kgL

Comment: this time the Office DLL **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Filters\offfiltx.dll** causes the search to crash the Explorer. Please install the Sp2 for Office 2010 and look if this fixes it.